# Заполнение массива чисел, предварительно прочитав их из файла. Java

Tags: java, массивы

Доброго времени суток. Есть следующая задача:
Первая строка в файле содержит число, обозначающее длину массива. Вторая строка содержит значения массива. Этими значениями необходимо заполнить наш массив. Проблема возникла именно с заполнением массива. Как сие реализовать?

```
import java.io.*;

public class taskTWO
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        double result = 0; //побочная переменная
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\input.txt")); //Файл для чтения
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\output.txt")); //Файл для записи

        //Читаем длину массива и создаем сам массив
        int length = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        int mass[] = new int[length];

        //Считываем вторую строку и заполняем
        String[] split = input.readLine().split(" ");

        //Дальше следует заполнение массива, которое, как выяснилось, в корне неверное
        for (String tmp : split)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++)
            {
                mass[i] = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
            }
        }

        //Выполняем алгоритм для побочной задачи
        for(int tmp : mass)
        {
            result += (tmp/2) / mass.length;
        }

        writer.print(result);

        input.close();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте посмотрим на ваш вложенный цикл for.

По вашей логике, вы для каждой строки из полученного массива строк split, начинаете заполнять значением из parse массив mass. В конечном итоге заполнится последним значением.

У вас совершается n*n действий, хотя это делается за n.

Тут будет достаточно пройтись один раз, да и результат вычислять здесь же:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++)
{
     mass[i] = Integer.parseInt(split[i]);
     result += (tmp/2) / mass.length;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В `stream api` это реализуется довольно тривиально:

```
 Integer[] array = Files
            //читаем из файла
            .lines(Paths.get("input.txt"))
            //пропускаем первую строку
            .skip(1)
            //разбиваем строки на слова
            .flatMap(str -> Stream.of(str.split(" ")))
            //преобразуем слова в числа
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            //пакуем все это в массив
            .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```